# Select 5 data points closest to SVM hyperlane

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I have written Python code using Sklearn to cluster my dataset:

```
af = AffinityPropagation().fit(X)
cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = af.labels_
n_clusters_= len(cluster_centers_indices)
```

I am exploring the use of query-by-clustering and so form an inital training dataset by:

```
td_title =[]
td_abstract = []
td_y= []
for each in centers:
    td_title.append(title[each])
    td_abstract.append(abstract[each])
    td_y.append(y[each])
```

I then train my model (an SVM) on it by:

```
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, data_y)
```

I wish to write a function that given the centres, the model, the X values and the Y values will append the 5 data points which the model is most unsure about, ie. the data points closest to the hyperplane. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first steps of your process aren't entirely clear to me, but here's a suggestion for "Select(ing) 5 data points closest to SVM hyperplane". The scikit documentation defines [`decision_function`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function) as the distance of the samples to the separating hyperplane.  The method returns an array which can be sorted with [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to find the "top/bottom N samples".

Following [this basic scikit example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-separating-hyperplane-py), define a function `closestN` to return the samples closest to the hyperplane.

```
import numpy as np

def closestN(X_array, n):
    # array of sample distances to the hyperplane
    dists = clf.decision_function(X_array)
    # absolute distance to hyperplane
    absdists = np.abs(dists)

    return absdists.argsort()[:n]
```

Add these two lines to the scikit example to see the function implemented:

```
closest_samples = closestN(X, 5)
plt.scatter(X[closest_samples][:, 0], X[closest_samples][:, 1], color='yellow')
```

### Original

[image]

### Closest Samples Highlighted

[image]

If you need to append the samples to some list, you could `somelist.append(closestN(X, 5))`.  If you needed the sample values you could do something like `somelist.append(X[closestN(X, 5)])`.

```
closestN(X, 5)
array([ 1, 20, 14, 31, 24])

X[closestN(X, 5)]
array([[-1.02126202,  0.2408932 ],
       [ 0.95144703,  0.57998206],
       [-0.46722079, -0.53064123],
       [ 1.18685372,  0.2737174 ],
       [ 0.38610215,  1.78725972]])
```